# Artifactory Debian repository reports "does not have a Release file"

Tags: artifactory, apt

So, I'm a noob to Artifactory.  I downloaded and installed the dockerized version of Pro - demo license, set up my first repository as a place to push internal packages we've developed for our ubuntu users.

However, when I upload a package and try to `sudo apt-get update` after adding a new ".list" file to my /etc/apt/sources.list.d, I get this message back:

```
W: The repository 'https://10.202.13.218/artifactory/ubuntu-dev-local xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Do I have to gpg sign the packages?  That seems like it would be a different error.

Comment: Same issue. Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error during install node js in debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251703/error-during-install-node-js-in-debian)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force artifactory to recreate the release.key file with the following API call:

```
curl -u admin:topsecret -X POST http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/deb/reindex/debian-local
```